# issue with nxlog - logs arrived tagged as USER.NOTICE

Tags: rsyslog, nxlog

First question here... I'm struggling with nxlog that behaves strangely: some logs doesn't enter my rsyslog fromhost-ip filtering rules when other work neatly, with the exact same config file, and fall down on the user.log file...

For what I have seen with tcpdump, it seems that the erroneous logs arrive already with some USER.NOTICE tag :
[image]

And even more, from the same machine, some logs arrive with the tag and some other without...

Can you give me some tracks to troubleshoot that?

here is the nxlog.conf:

```
    Panic Soft
#NoFreeOnExit TRUE

define ROOT     C:\Program Files\nxlog
define CERTDIR  %ROOT%\cert
define CONFDIR  %ROOT%\conf\nxlog.d
define LOGDIR   %ROOT%\data

define LOGFILE  %LOGDIR%\nxlog.log
LogFile %LOGFILE%

Moduledir %ROOT%\modules
CacheDir  %ROOT%\data
Pidfile   %ROOT%\data\nxlog.pid
SpoolDir  %ROOT%\data

<Extension _syslog>
    Module      xm_syslog
</Extension>

<Extension _charconv>
    Module      xm_charconv
    AutodetectCharsets iso8859-2, utf-8, utf-16, utf-32
</Extension>

<Extension _exec>
    Module      xm_exec
</Extension>

<Extension _fileop>
    Module      xm_fileop

    # Check the size of our log file hourly, rotate if larger than 5MB
    <Schedule>
        Every   1 hour
        Exec    if (file_exists('%LOGFILE%') and \
                   (file_size('%LOGFILE%') >= 5M)) \
                    file_cycle('%LOGFILE%', 8);
    </Schedule>

    # Rotate our log file every week on Sunday at midnight
    <Schedule>
        When    @weekly
        Exec    if file_exists('%LOGFILE%') file_cycle('%LOGFILE%', 8);
    </Schedule>
</Extension>

# Snare compatible example configuration
# Collecting event log
 <Input in>
     Module      im_msvistalog
 </Input>
# 
# Converting events to Snare format and sending them out over TCP syslog
 <Output out>
     Module      om_udp
     Host        SYSLOG_IP
     Port        514
     Exec        to_syslog_snare();
 </Output>
 
 # Connect input 'in' to output 'out'
 <Route 1>
     Path        in => out
 </Route>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide more information; What exactly does not work? What have you tried to solve the problem? Also, please avoid posting pictures and instead format the message as text.

Comment: As SO is a Q&A site for programming(-related) questions, I recommend you post your question on a SE site like [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [superuser](https://superuser.com/), on which your question is way better of - which increases the likelihood that your question is answered.